# Realizar inserción dentro de un bucle for

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Hola a todos y muchas gracias de antemano.
Quiero insertar los datos que arroja el bucle for, pero que la inserción se realice  en cada ciclo del bucle, el problema es que no me ejecuta otra cosa mas que la linear de inserción, por ejemplo la linea de impresión solo se ejecuta una vez.

```
import sqlite3


conexion = sqlite3.connect('Base.db')
cursor   = conexion.cursor()
#cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE TablaUno (Codigo INTEGER(20),Nombre VARCHAR(20))")
#cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TablaUno VALUES ('3','Robert Galarga')")
#conexion.commit()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TablaUno")

for Columna in cursor:
    print (Columna[0],Columna[1])
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TablaUno VALUES ('"+str(Columna[0])+"','"+str(Columna[1])+"')")
    conexion.commit()
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta? Qué problema tienes con tu código?

Comment: Ya edite, mis disculpas.

Comment: El problema es que solo se ejecuta la linea de código con la inserción, la linea de impresión solo de ejecuta una vez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haces un execute pero te hace falta usar `fetchAll()` para traer los resultados de la ejecución a tu cursor y así poderlo recorrer como deseas (de hecho, no haces ningún fetch y no es que las filas queden en el cursor; esa instancia es mucho más compleja que una lista):

```
import sqlite3

conexion = sqlite3.connect('Base.db')
cursor   = conexion.cursor()
#cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE TablaUno (Codigo INTEGER(20),Nombre VARCHAR(20))")
#cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TablaUno VALUES ('3','Robert Galarga')")
#conexion.commit()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TablaUno")

records = cursor.fetchall()

for Columna in records:
    print (Columna[0],Columna[1])
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TablaUno VALUES ('"+str(Columna[0])+"','"+str(Columna[1])+"')")
    conexion.commit()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto resuelve muchos problemas.